# WinForm with UserControl containing DataGridView causes Designer issue

Tags: winforms, visual-studio-2008, user-controls, datagridview, designer

I have a very strange issue and am not sure why it is happening or how to prevent it.
Envionment:
.NET Framework 3.5
WinForm application
C#
VS2008 Pro

Issue:
I have a WinForm containing a TabControl which has a custom usercontrol on two of its TabPage.
The usercontrol i created contains 3 DataGridView controls.

Everytime I go into Desiger of my WinForm, I see that there are SIX (3 * 2) instances of a DataGridView control created.
They are all numbered such as dataGridView13, dataGridView14, etc...
Along each of those DataGridView instances, the associated DataGridViewTextBoxColumn and DataGridViewCellStyle instances are also created.
Pretty soon I had nearly 600 DataGridView instances in the MyWinForm.Designer.cs file!!

Why is this happening and more importantly how to prevent it???
Anyone has seen something like this before??

Comment: I think you might need to post the usercontrol's code.

Answer (score 0):

The designer in Visual Studio has problems handling inherited controls, especially so with the DataGridView control. If it is also a container for child controls, like columns, a new set of children will be generated every time you save a modification.

The only way I have found to address the problem is to make your modifications, save them, then remove the previous list of duplicated controls. The designer at least has the courtesy to number them sequentially by type of control.

Oh, and save yourself the frustration of renaming any of the controls. When the designer generates the new set, it reverts to its default naming practices.

Sorry I don't have better news for you.